# error on Series is ambiguous, using list() to pass variables to function

Tags: python, pandas

Simple create list() of variables and pass to function. In which function will assign list items using `n`, as in `model_m[n+1]`. Made mistake on passing list() to function and now error on Series is ambiguous, it's know that python functions hide some bool calls any(), all(), bool(), item().

def arima_forecast() was compiled BEFORE, I accidentally listed it here in reverse order

Need to learn how to pass an empty list() variable to function.

The goal is to test boolean of  (wd.weather_data['callsign'] == column). Then if TRUE, select weather_data['collsign'] data.frame column that equates to the value of the passed in column variable. Then use that selected data, loc[wd.weather_data['callsign'], to invoke the ARIMA function using the assigned variable 'wdata' with that sub-selected data. I have already executed tests on auto.arima() to determine the best order terms [ arima(p,d,q) ], which are here labeled ARIMA(...order=(2,1,1))

```
def arima_forecast(column, n, model_m, model_f, model_4):
  n = n+1
  if (wd.weather_data['callsign'] == column):
    wdata = wd.weather_data.loc[wd.weather_data['callsign'] == column]
    model = ARIMA(wdata['prcp'], order=(2,1,1))    
    model_m[n] = model
    # model_f[n] = model_fit #future effort to do
    # model_4[n] = model_forecast #future effort to do

model_m = list()
model_f = list()
model_4 = list()
n = int()
# for example, send city name and [] empty list vars
for column in df_all_city_names:
  arima_forecast_test('Amarillo', 0, [], [], [])
```

The individual components of the function arima_forecast() were tested and working ok before being wrapped into a function. The ARIMA model was testing and working ok.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-679f1b17139b> in <module>()
      5 
      6 for column in df_all_city_names:
----> 7   arima_forecast(column, n, model_m=None, model_f=None, model_4=None)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1536     def __nonzero__(self):
   1537         raise ValueError(
-> 1538             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1539             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1540         )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: I'm not really following. What's your question? Where's the list? Why does `def arima_forecast` come *after* the call to `arima_forecast`? If it's not supposed to be after, then what do you want `wd.weather_data['callsign'] == column` to do exactly? Is it `column` that's supposed to be a list? Or if it is in fact supposed to be a `Series`, then what should happen? The error message explains what the options are. If you still need help, please read [ask] and make a [mre].

Comment: the column in wd.weather_data[] is to match on the value in ['callsign'] variable in same name, and check for == then apply list updates. Column is not Series, just a 'column' in a data.frame

Answer (score 0):

I was not using series data but got caught on the ambiguous of my data usage, so I needed to research how to handle ValueError in Python, I worked more on Java in my past career. For this solution, as the error message indicated, needed was a .all() function to be appended to handle the ValueError in Python.

```
(wd.weather_data['callsign'] == column).any()
```